# Eclipse plugins background color change

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have installed eclipse classic for java and I installed *php plugin* and *aptana rad rails plugin for rails*. I can import the preference file epf and that will change the common files background color. But for php files its not reflecting how do i change the background color of an installed plugin

Thanks

Sreeraj

Answer (score 1):

For PHP look for this in preferences:

```
PHP -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring
```

This *might* differ for the plugins you use because plugins can introduce that on their own and not all use the `General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts` preferences.

To find out which Editor/Plugin is used for the file-type in question you can look under

```
General -> Editors -> File Associations
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when I had PHPeclipse and Aptana plugIn installed. In the top toolbar (next to the printer symbol) you should be able to choose the theme.